# CRM 2016 not liking Javascript using if-else

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

Can anyone tell me what CRM would hate about this onload function I've created?

It's telling me Form_OnLoad is not defined.  Looks defined to me.  It's enabled in my form onload, published, etc.

Thank you.

```
function Form_OnLoad() {
    //Calculates total commission for AE1

    // Products + Services
    if (Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_commissionproductae1").getValue() !== null) && (Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_commissionserviceae1").getValue() !== null) && (Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_commissionseligible").getValue() == "Yes") {
        var comm1 = (Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_commissionproductae1").getValue() + Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_commissionserviceae1").getValue());
        Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_commissiontotalae1").setValue(comm1);   
    } else if {
    // Products only
    (Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_commissionproductae1").getValue() !== null) && (Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_commissionseligible").getValue() == "Yes") {
        Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_commissiontotalae1").setValue(Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_commissionproductae1").getValue());  
    } else if {
    // Services only
    (Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_commissionserviceae1").getValue() !== null) && (Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_commissionseligible").getValue() == "Yes") {
        Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_commissiontotalae1").setValue(Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_commissionserviceae1").getValue());  
    } else {
    // Net Sales 
    (Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_commissionnetae1").getValue() !== null) && (Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_commissionseligible").getValue() == "Yes") {
        Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_commissiontotalae1").setValue(Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_commissionserviceae1").getValue());  
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that's because your JavaScript is not correct. Try to use following code instead of yours:

```
function Form_OnLoad() { //Calculates total commission for AE1

    // Products + Services
    if (Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_commissionproductae1").getValue() !== null && 
        Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_commissionserviceae1").getValue() !== null && 
        Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_commissionseligible").getValue() === "Yes") {
        var comm1 = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_commissionproductae1").getValue() + Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_commissionserviceae1").getValue();
        Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_commissiontotalae1").setValue(comm1);   
    } else if (Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_commissionproductae1").getValue() !== null && 
        Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_commissionseligible").getValue() === "Yes") {
        Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_commissiontotalae1").setValue(Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_commissionproductae1").getValue());  
    } else if (Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_commissionserviceae1").getValue() !== null &&
        Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_commissionseligible").getValue() === "Yes") {
        Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_commissiontotalae1").setValue(Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_commissionserviceae1").getValue());  
    } else if (Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_commissionnetae1").getValue() !== null &&
        Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_commissionseligible").getValue() === "Yes") {
        Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_commissiontotalae1").setValue(Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_commissionserviceae1").getValue());  
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Andrii.  I think i see the error in my code where I was trying to do the and without the right (), and the ===.  I'm no longer getting the script error.  Appreciate it.  One addition - if i wanted to check for not null *or* = 0, do you know how i'd adjust this?

Comment: If you want to check bot you can do following: var a = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("name").getValue(); if (a != null && a != 0) {//your logic}